# Power BI Subscription History

Tags: powerbi

Is it possible to view the subscription history? Who did we have subscribed to said report? Do we manually have to add it back once it gets deleted as in if a report got deleted?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the perfect answer to your questions.

Due to the fact that subscriptions are not managed on the workspace level but rather on the user level, it's hard to obtain current subscription configuration information on the tenant scope. The user has only access to subscription list created by him. When the report will be deleted you have to add the subscription again when it will be published again. If the report is updated you don't have to recreate the subscription.

The administrator or user with access to audit log is able to obtain information about all subscriptions operations such as create, update and delete subscription with configuration detail from the audit log. Each log entry recorded for activity:

- Created Power BI email subscription
- Updated Power BI email subscription
- Deleted Power BI email subscription

Has detailed information about the report, page and subscribed email addresses. The problem with Audit log is that this information is purged after 90 days so it's hard to obtain the complete configuration of subscriptions for the tenant.

Unfortunately, I don't have tenant admin right to check if there is any other method to get such information on admin level.